# (beginner) How do I assign these values to a string?

Tags: function

I need to create a string `s` of 1's and 0's. The string is created from the values returned by the function `isSet`. It always returns either `1` or `0`. I cannot simply put `isSet` into an `if` statement to add `1` or `0` to the string because the program will not compile. I'm a newbie. I'm wondering if there's a simple way to loop my `isSet` function while assigning it's return values to my string `s`, all while its inside `bitsetfn`. Any help is appreciated. In c++

```
int isSet(unsigned int x, int i)
{
    return ((x >> i) & 1);
}

string bitsetfn(int nbits, unsigned int x)
{
    string s;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        isSet(x, i);
        if (isSet = 0)
        {
            s = s + "0";
        }
        if (isSet = 1)
        {
            s = s + "1";
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: It might help to tell us which language this is.

Comment: @Dukeling: it's definitely a C syntax based one, so the answer will be pretty much the same in any case :)

Comment: @Candlejack: you're supposed to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in that code is that you're calling the function `isSet` with some arguments, and then, figuratively speaking, throwing away the return value (i.e. the value of the function application) by not storing it in a variable nor using immediately in e.g. an `if` statement.

You are then using the function itself (as opposed to the value of applying that function, or, the return value of that function when called with arguments) to compare it against `0` and `1`, which is not the right thing to do.

Instead, what you should do, is:

```
if (isSet(x, 1) == 1) {
    ...
}
if (isSet(x, 1) == 0) {
    ...
}
```

(**Note:** the comparison operator is `==` not `=`, which is the assignment operator—this holds in almost all modern programming langauges.)

which can be shortened to:

```
if (isSet(x, 1) == 1) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

...and, in programming languages that treat `1` and `0` as the boolean values True and False (C, C++, Python, PHP, etc but not Java nor C#), you can reduce that to:

```
if (isSet(x, 1)) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Furthermore, in general, especially in the case of functions with side-effects (i.e. functions that either return different values from consequent calls, or that modify their environment, or both), you will want to store the return value of the function call in a variable, if you're going to do more than just a single `if` or `if-else` on it:

```
 int rnd = generateRandomValue();  // return different values on consequent calls
 if (rnd < 0.25) {
     doSomething();
 } else if (rnd < 0.5) {
     doSomethingElse();
 } else {
     doSomethingThird();
 }
```

in the above example, if you just called `generateRandomValue()` in both the `if` as well as the `else if` lines, they'd be inspecting 2 completely different values, leading to faulty logic.

**P.S.** Depending on the programming language, the entire program could be significantly reduced (e.g. even a single line, without necessarily impairing readability), but this is outside of the scope of this question.

Answer (score -1):

You're forgetting to store the returned value from `isSet()` as a local variable. So this line:

```
isSet(x, i);
```

should really be:

```
int isSet = isSet(x, i);
```

Then when you have a reference to `isSet` in later lines, it will be defined.

**EDIT**: Please note that, just as the comments state, having a variable with the same name as the function is generally not a good idea. You could either name the variable differently (and change the references to it in later lines as appropriate) or do as the other answer suggests and call the function in your comparison.

Comment: The variable name having the same name as the function is bound to lead to confusion (I don't think it's 'forgetting', I think it's 'not knowing').

Comment: Not only confusion but very likely either a runtime or compilation error, depending on language.

Comment: Yeah you guys are right, I was just trying to keep as much as possible to the original code. Updated my answer to reflect.